# www folder not found after i created cordova based application in xcode

Tags: iphone, cordova

I created a Cordova based application in XCode, and when I tried to the `www` folder of my project I did not find it.

Can anyone advise me where to find the `www` folder that should be included in the project?

Comment: Hi! Which version of Phonegap / Cordova are you using?

Comment: you need to run the project once, and it will be created

Comment: i ran the the project but it failed to build it is giving error 'NSAutoReleasePool' unavailable. ARC forbids explicit message send of 'release'

Comment: are you creating it by command-line ?

Comment: no i used the run button in xcode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the tutorial provided by the online doc very carefully:

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.5.0/guide_getting-started_ios_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20iOS

Normally, when creating your project, you should have turned off the ARC:

[image: 1]

In case you forgot to turn the ARC off, you may try the following:

1. Select your project file.
2. Select the `Build settings` tab, and select the filter options `All` and `levels` (default is `Combined`).
3. In the search field to the right of the filter option `Combined`, enter `automatic`.
4. There will be a group called `Apple LLVM Compiler 3.0 – Language` containing the line `Objective-C Automatic Reference Counting`.
5. Click that line, then in the middle column (where it says `yes`), click and choose `no`.

The above should turn your ARC off.

Then, try following the next steps of the project creation:

> - You should see your project in Xcode 4 now. Press the **Run** button in
>     the top left corner. Your build should succeed and launch in the
>     simulator
> - You should see a error in your simulator informing you
>     index.html was not found
> - To fix this, we need to copy the **www**
>     directory into the project. Right click on the project in the left
>     navigation window and click show in finder
> - In Finder, you should see
>     the **www** directory beside your project
> - Next step is **IMPORTANT**! Drag the **www** folder into Xcode 4. You can't
>     just drag the www folder into your app's folder. It needs to be
>     dragged into Xcode 4!! In my case I would drag it and drop it on
>     HiWorld shown below.

[image: 2]

> After you drag, you should see a prompt with a few options. Make sure
>   to select Create folder references for any added folders. Click Finish

[Continue from step **4.HelloWorld** of the online doc...](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.5.0/guide_getting-started_ios_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20iOS)

Hope this helps.